# Hibernate creates two tables in a many to many relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my `Product` entity class:

```
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
  @Column
  @ManyToMany()
  private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

  @ManyToOne
  private Supplier supplier;
}
```

And this is my `Customer` entity class:

```
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

  //Enum type to String type in database '_'
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column
  private Type type;

  @Column
  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Product.class)
  private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I run my Spring boot project, it creates 2 separate tables in my database(Mysql): **product_customer** and **customer_product** but I need only one. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Without `@JoinTable`, it's not bidirectional relation rather two unidirectional relations for both side that's why two tables created. Try to define join table with `@JoinTable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the following [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) to know how to map a `ManyToMany` relation in a suitable way. But basically, you can do:

```
public class Product {
  ...

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE
  })
  @JoinTable(name="product_customer"
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
  )
  private Set<Customer> customers = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  ...
}
```

And:

```
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

  ...
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customers")
  private Set<Product> products = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  ...
}
```

As @Kavithakaran mentioned in a comment of his answer, you can use `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = ...` once you identify the "owner of the relation".

Answer (score 3):

Update your classes as follows:

```
   public class Product {

     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name="product_customer"
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
     )
     private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
     ...
   }
```

```
    public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

      @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(name="product_customer"
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="customer_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id")
      )
      private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
      ...
    }
```

Comment: In customer size `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customers")` is sufficient I think

Comment: True. Once he identifies one side as owning side. I will leave the answer as it is because `@doctore` has put that as answer

Comment: Added an update in my answer to clarify that point to @AliBooresh

Comment: @doctore, Thanks. We are all here to learn from each other

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you don't want to create the third table then you can read the following link below:-
[Hibernate Many to Many without third table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307406/hibernate-many-to-many-without-third-table)

Otherwise, you can do this with @jointable annotation.