# Many to one relationship without a join table in spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to build the relationship between two tables using spring-data jpa. I have read many SO articles like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014649/many-to-many-association-without-join-table), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307406/hibernate-many-to-many-without-third-table) but they are pretty old and don't seem to apply to my specific use case. Hence this question:

There are 2 tables `user_client_scopes` and `scopes` listed below.

```
user_client_scopes:
user_id (long),
client_id (string)
last_updated (timestamp)
scope_id (Foreign key to scopes table),
primary key (user_id, client_id, scope_id)

scopes:
id (int, primary key)
name (string)
```

A `<user_id, client_id>` can have multiple scopes. Similarly, the same scope can be held by many <user_id, client_id>s. Hence the many-to-many relationship. The join table (as defined by spring-data-jpa) is kind of embedded within `user_client_scope` table.

Here is a half-written-code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_client_scopes")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@IdClass(UserClientScopesPK.class)
public class UserClientScopes implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private String clientId;

    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    private Timestamp lastUpdated;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "scope_id")
    private int scopeId;

    @ManyToMany // <- how to complete this definition?
    private Set<Scope> scopes;

    getters and setters.
```

Here are 2 other classes (for the sake of completion).

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserClientScopesPK implements Serializable {
    private long userId;
    private String clientId;
    private int scopeId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "scopes")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Scope implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;
}
```

How do I complete the `user_client_scopes` entity such that we can:

1. Find all scopes for a given <user_id, client_id>. i.e. execute the following SQL:

```
select user_id, client_id, scope 
from scopes
join user_client_scopes ucs on ucs.scope_id = scopes.id
where ucs.user_id = ? and ucs.client_id = ?
```

2. Save new scopes for a given <user_id, client_id>. i.e. execute the following SQL:

```
insert into user_client_scopes (user_id, client_id, scope_id, last_updated)
select ?, ?, id, now()
from scopes
where scopes.name = ?
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Changing title to *Many to one* instead of *Many to many* relationship.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a many-to-many because the association `scope` is mapped by the column `scope_id` in `user_client_scopes`. This means that if I take a single row in the table `user_client_scopes`, it will be associated to only a single row in the table `scopes`. Therefore, this is a many-to-one.

If the three columns `<user_id, client_id, scope_id>` form the key for `user_client_scopes`, then the mapping for the table should look like:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "user_client_scopes")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@IdClass(UserClientScopesPK.class)
public class UserClientScopes implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private String clientId;

    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    private Timestamp lastUpdated;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinedColumn(name = "scope_id")
    private Scope scope;


    getters and setters.
}

class UserClientScopesPK implements Serializable {

    private long userId;
    private String clientId;
    private Scope scope;

    // getters,setters, equals and hascode
}
```

With this mapping you can run the following HQL:

```
select ucs
from UserClientScopes ucs join ucs.scope
where ucs.userId = :userId and ucs.clientId = :clientId
```

It will return all `UserClientScopes` entities matching the selected pair `<userId, clientId>`. Each one with a different scope.

Or, if you only care about the scope:

```
select s
from UserClientScopes ucs join ucs.scope s
where ucs.userId = :userId and ucs.clientId = :clientId
```

With Spring Data JPA, it will look like this:

```
@Query("select s from UserClientScopes ucs join ucs.scope swhere ucs.userId = ?1 and ucs.clientId = ?2")
public List<Scope> findScopesByUserIdAndClientId(long userId, String clientId);
```

or

```
@Query("select s.name from UserClientScopes ucs join ucs.scope swhere ucs.userId = ?1 and ucs.clientId = ?2")
public List<String> findScopesNameByUserIdAndClientId(long userId, String clientId);
```

You can also run the insert query as native SQL (you can probably run something similar as HQL, but I don't remember the right syntax now. I will update the answer later).

One last thing, to keep track of the last updated time, you could use [Spring Entity callback listener](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa#2-adding-springs-entity-callback-listener):

```
@Entity
...
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class UserClientScopes implements Serializable {

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    private Date lastUpdated;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This *almost* works. I was also able to enhance this suggestion for database updates by creating a list of UserClientScopes object with references to the scope parameter (determined using findScopeByName query). One follow up though: In the `findUserClientScopesByUserIdAndClientId`, I see 2 selects:
1. Select scope_id from UserClientScopes table by user_id and client_id.
2. Use the selected scope_id from step 1 to determine the name of the scope.

Instead of 2 selects, how can I configure the entity to do one query that joins both the table? FetchMode.JOIN doesn't help.

Comment: You don't need to run two queries once you have the `UserClientScopes`.You could do `userClientScope.getScope().getName()`. If you are only interested to the scope. You need to use the `@Query` annotation. Or you can use `@Query` and return directly a list of scopes, if that's whay you need. I will update my answer with an example